# What are Expressions in English Grammar?

Tags: expressions, comparison, colloquial-language

Moreover what are **Idiomatic Expressions** and what are **Colloquial Expressions**?

Comment: If you google either of those holder phrases, you'll get solid definitions for them, from several sources.

Comment: **Expression** is not a technical term with a defined meaning in linguistics, so we cannot answer your title question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idiomatic expressions:

Idiomatic expressions are a type of informal English that have a meaning different from the meaning of the words in the expression. Here's an example of an idiomatic expression.

Examples:

A penny for your thoughts:
A way of asking what someone is thinking

Actions speak louder than words:
People's intentions can be judged better by what they do than what they say.

Add insult to injury:
To further a loss with mockery or indignity; to worsen an unfavorable situation.

An arm and a leg:
Very expensive or costly. A large amount of money.

At the drop of a hat:
without any hesitation; instantly.

Back to the drawing board:
When an attempt fails and it's time to start all over.

Ball is in your court:
It is up to you to make the next decision or step

Barking up the wrong tree:
Looking in the wrong place. Accusing the wrong person

Be glad to see the back of:
Be happy when a person leaves.

Beat around the bush:
Avoiding the main topic. Not speaking directly about the issue.

Best of both worlds:
All the advantages.

Best thing since sliced bread:
A good invention or innovation. A good idea or plan.

Bite off more than you can chew:
To take on a task that is way to big.

Blessing in disguise:
Something good that isn't recognized at first.

Burn the midnight oil:
To work late into the night, alluding to the time before electric lighting.

Can't judge a book by its cover:
Cannot judge something primarily on appearance.

Caught between two stools:
When someone finds it difficult to choose between two alternatives.

Costs an arm and a leg:
This idiom is used when something is very expensive.

colloquialism:

a word, phrase, or expression characteristic of ordinary or familiar conversation rather than formal speech or writing, as “She’s out” for “She is not at home.”

Colloquialism Definition. In literature, colloquialism is the use of informal words, phrases or even slang in a piece of writing. Colloquial expressions tend to sneak in as writers, being part of a society, are influenced by the way people speak in that society.

Examples of Colloquialism from Common Speech

As stated above, there are three different types of colloquialisms that we can distinguish: words, phrases, and aphorisms. Words can be colloquialism examples if they demonstrate the regional dialect of the speaker, or if they are contractions or examples of profanity. Phrases and aphorisms are colloquialisms if they aren’t literal usages, yet are widely understand within a geographical boundary.

Words:

Regional differences: One famous colloquial difference in the United States is the way a person refers to a carbonated beverage. There are regional borders that separate the usage of the words “soda”, “pop”, “soft drink”, and “Coke” (used as a generic term and not just to refer to the brand). There are numerous differences between American English and British English, such as “truck”/“lorry”, “soccer”/“football”, and “parakeet”/“budgie”.

Contractions: Words such as “ain’t” and “gonna” are examples of colloquialism, as they are not used widely throughout English-speaking populations.
Profanity: Some words are considered profane in some dialects of English where they are not at all bad in other dialects. A good example is the word “bloody” which is a simple adjective in American English, but is a curse word in British English.

Phrases:

Old as the hills

Penny-pincher

She’ll be right (Australian English, meaning everything will be all right)

Pass the buck

Eat my dust

Aphorisms:

I wasn’t born yesterday.

There’s more than one way to skin a cat.

Put your money where your mouth is.

You’re driving me up the wall.

Idiom vs colloquialism:

An idiom is a phrase that is more than the sum of its parts, or in other words, has more of a meaning than the individual words used in the phrase. Examples include pay the piper, for the birds, and pulling one’s leg. Idiom is also a synonym for dialect, a way of speech particular to a geographical area that has specific vocabulary, syntax, and grammar. Finally, it can be used to describe a method of expression particular to a person, time period, or object.

A colloquialism is a phrase that has risen from verbal speech. The only criteria for this designation is that the word or phrase be extremely informal. They may originate from a dialect, but do not have to. Examples include a whole nother, could care less, and raring to.